# RPI How to prioritize an external bluetooth antenna over the internal antenna

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

The Raspberry pi's bluetooth antenna isn't strong enough for my needs, so I've connected external bluetooth USB antennas and was able to improve the signal quality. To force the RPI to use the external USB antenna I've added the following lines at the end of the config.txt file located at /boot:

```
dtoverlay=disable-bt
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

It correctly disables the bluetooth internal antenna during the boot forcing the use of the external one. The problem is that if the external antenna isn't connected, the bluetooth doesn't work. Although most of the times the external antenna will be connected to the board, I want to have a fallback solution for the few cases where it won't be connected.

Is there any way I can prioritize the use of the external antenna, but use the internal one if the external one isn't connected?
Is there any way I can implement this with a script or should I implement it in the Python code of the program I developed that is running in the RPI?

Answer (score 0):

Since you write about the Bluetooth antenna but deactivate the Bluetooth hardware/chip, I'll stick with Bluetooth adapter for my answer, which seems more technically correct to me.

Since Linux supports several Bluetooth adapters at the same time, the solution is as follows:
Do not disable the internal Bluetooth adapter of your Raspberry Pi. If the external adapter is connected, use the external adapter, otherwise use the internal one.

And, there might be another solution for your problem: [Add External Antenna to Pi 3 and Pi 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZGMGs6RDtc)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to automate that priority selection. Just to clarify, it's a USB antenna, I'm not soldering it

Comment: First adapter is called `hci0`, the second one `hci1` and so on. You might have to explain a little more precisely what software problem you have with your task. It would be best if you showed us the corresponding [source code excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Assuming you're still having this problem @TOKSSS, what application are you using that is trying to use Bluetooth?